# WordPress: custom styles being overridden by Bootstrap styles

Tags: wordpress

I am a WordPress beginner who has taken over management of an existing WordPress site. I've established that a little problem I am seeing is to do with the order of loading of CSS files. When I view page source, I can see this towards the bottom of the head (site name changed for security):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='addtoany-css'  href='https://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/addtoany.min.css?ver=1.16' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='mysite-style-css'  href='https://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mysite-acf/assets/css/mysite.css?ver=1674048874' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-style-css'  href='https://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mysite-acf/assets/css/bootstrap.css?ver=1643275784' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

So the custom CSS for the theme (mysite.css) is being overridden by the next line which sets everything back to Bootstrap defaults.

Where in WordPress are such things determined, and how can I set it so that the Bootstrap CSS loads first and is then potentially overridden by theme CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_style('main-style','http://website.com/styles/main.css');
}, 99);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Be sure you got wp_head() in your header file.

Comment: Thanks. What does this do? And am I right in thinking that the actual stylesheet I should reference would be the one which is https://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mysite-acf/assets/css/mysite.css in my original post?

Comment: In this approach you can take is to utilize the wp_enqueue_scripts hook/function to set a low/high  priority for your stylesheet being processed. This way you can guarantee that styles load after/before all the default ones within WordPress. It's worth mentioning that if this still loads before/after another CSS file in the HEAD of the page you should bump up the number from 10 to some other higher number to move it down/higher in priority and load later/before.